# Error occurred in update_chart_lines: Can only use .str accessor with string values

Tags: python, pandas, charts, lightweight-charts

I am struggling to get the .update to work on my line objects. I am pretty sure I have the correct format for the pd.Series and have followed the docs to the best of my ability.

terminal output states:

> Received avg_series_high:  2024-03-05 3693.797625 dtype: float64

I then receive the following error:

> Error occurred in update_chart_lines: Can only use .str accessor with
> string values!

I have never seen this error before whilst use pd and all examples of this error i have found online seem to indicate that the name of the series may not automatically be being treated as a string?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Code example

```
async def update_chart_lines(self, avg_line_high, avg_line_low, avg_line_high2, avg_line_low2, queue):
        print("Starting update_chart_lines function")
        avg_data = None

        while True:
            try:
                avg_data = await queue.get()

                if avg_data is not None and 'date' in avg_data:

                    avg_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(avg_data['date'], unit='ms')
                    # Create a pandas Series for each line
                    avg_series_high_data = pd.Series([avg_data['avg_last_candles_high']], index=[avg_data['date']])
                    avg_series_low_data = pd.Series([avg_data['avg_last_candles_low']], index=[avg_data['date']])
                    avg_series_high2_data = pd.Series([avg_data['avg_last_candles_high2']], index=[avg_data['date']])
                    avg_series_low2_data = pd.Series([avg_data['avg_last_candles_low2']], index=[avg_data['date']])

                    print(f"Received avg_series_high: {avg_series_high_data}")

                    # Update each line with the corresponding pandas Series
                    avg_line_high.update(avg_series_high_data)
                    avg_line_low.update(avg_series_low_data)
                    avg_line_high2.update(avg_series_high2_data)
                    avg_line_low2.update(avg_series_low2_data)
                else:
                    print("No avg candle ticks to process.")
                    continue
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred in update_chart_lines: {e}")
```

This generates a dataframe continuously and sends it to update_chart_lines:

```
async def last_candles_cont(df, n, timeframe, queue):

  timeframe = timeframe

  """ print(f"Calculating average of last {n} candles for {timeframe} timeframe") """

  multipliers = {
    '1d': 1.025,
    '4h': 1.015,
    '1h': 1.01,
    '15m': 1.005,
    '5m': 1.001,
    '1m': 1.00
  }

  while True:
    try:  

      avg_data = None
          
      tick= await queue.get()

      print(f"Received tick: {tick}")

      tick_df = pd.DataFrame(tick, index=[0])

      df = pd.concat([df, tick_df], ignore_index=True)

      """ df['diff'] = df['close'] - df['close'].shift(1)
      print (df['diff'])

      # Calculate the rate of change as a percentage
      df['roc'] = df['diff'] / df['close'].shift(1) * 100
      print (df['roc']) """

      multiplier = multipliers[timeframe]

      df['avg_last_candles_high'] = (df['high']*multiplier).shift(1).rolling(n).mean()
      df['avg_last_candles_low'] = (df['low']/multiplier).shift(1).rolling(n).mean()

      df['avg_last_candles_high2'] = (df['high']*multiplier).rolling(n).mean()
      df['avg_last_candles_low2'] = (df['low']/multiplier).rolling(n).mean()

      avg_data = pd.DataFrame({
              'date': (df['date']),
              'avg_last_candles_high': df['avg_last_candles_high'],
              'avg_last_candles_low': df['avg_last_candles_low'],
              'avg_last_candles_high2': df['avg_last_candles_high2'],
              'avg_last_candles_low2': df['avg_last_candles_low2'],
          }).dropna()
      
      current_candle = avg_data.tail(1).squeeze()
      print(f"Current candle: {current_candle}")
      # Put the current candle into the queue
      await queue.put(current_candle)

      await asyncio.sleep(1)

      """ return avg_data """

    except Exception as e:
      print(f"Error in avg candle function: {e}")
      return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame in case of error
```

Comment: it would help if you remove the `try...except` and see exactly where the error occurs, then show us a) the dtype of the series being used b) its index and c) the stack trace

Comment: Hi Josh, Thanks for taking a look at this. I have an example of the dtype in the original message.

terminal output states:

Received avg_series_high: 2024-03-05 3693.797625 dtype: float64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have experience with `lightweight-charts`, but your problem seems related to the data you're passing to `.update`.

### Problem

You're creating pandas series like this:

```
avg_series_high_data = pd.Series([avg_data['avg_last_candles_high']], index=[avg_data['date']])
```

Which effectively creates a series with dates as index and corresponding values for each date. Something similar to this:

```
2024-03-11    1
2024-03-12    2
2024-03-13    3
2024-03-14    4
```

The issue is `lightweight-charts` is expecting pandas series in a different format, i.e., a series for each row of the dataframe you're plotting, with values for an index 'date', another index 'some_value'... and so on. So something more along the lines of:

```
date      2016-12-28 00:00:00
open                  14.6667
high                    14.92
low                     14.48
close                  14.616
volume             48715005.0
```

### Error message

The error you're seeing happens because `lightweight-charts` is expecting `date` or `time` to be in the series index. If it isn't, it assumes these words may be in uppercase and [calls `.str.lower()` on it](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alouisnw01%2Flightweight-charts-python%20.str.&type=code).

In the series you're passing it, the index values are of type `datetime`, so it raises the error:

> Error occurred in update_chart_lines: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

### What to do

You need to create pandas series in the format suggested above. I don't have access to your data, so it's hard to recommend anything more concrete. Since it's a line, I assume each series would look something like this:

```
date      2016-12-28 00:00:00
open                  14.6667
```

Comment: Hi e-motta, Thank you for the in depth analysis.

I have amended my approach to be in line with your suggestion.

avg_candles_high_series:
date                     2024-03-12 00:00:00
avg_last_candles_high            4096.579062
Name: date, dtype: object
avg_candles_low_series:
date                    2024-03-12 00:00:00
avg_last_candles_low            3708.346341
Name: date, dtype: object

The docs state- update(series: pd.Series), Updates the data for the line. This should be given as a Series object, with labels time | value.

Error: float floor division by zero

Comment: @Yan Can you edit your question and update it with the new info? It's hard to understand it in the comment.

Comment: From a first glance, seems like you should name your series `'avg_last_candles_high'` and `'avg_last_candles_low'` (with `series.name = new_name...`.